# Python Types of Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm going to have an exam on python soon and while I was solving exams from previous years I noticed that sometimes we are asked to write a recursive function. **My question is:** Can I use any type of recursion?
For instance, if I was given this exercise:

> Write a recursive function that returns the number of even digits in
>   the given argument

In most of the exercises that ask for a recursive function the teacher's solution is very similar to the function even_occ_DO. Would the even_occ_T also be accepted as a correct answer (I think it will but I want to be sure)?

```
def even_occ_DO(number): #Recursion using delayed operations 
  if number == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return (1 if number % 2 == 0 else 0) + even_occ_DO(number//10)

def even_occ_T(number): #Tail Recursion
  def aux(number, sum_):
    if number == 0:
        return sum_
    else:
        return aux(number//10, sum_ + (1 if number%2 == 0 else 0))
  return aux(number,0)
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with *type* of recursion?

Comment: Furthermore I think you address those questions better to your professor/TA/...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem By type of recursion I mean all the different ways to make a recursive function (linear recursion, tail recursion, binary recursion, ...)

Comment: I assume every recursive function would be accepted. If a specific type is required it should be explicitly mentioned. This is programming after all; we have to be explicit.

Comment: FWIW, both versions return 0 for an arg of 0; they should return 1. It's easy to fix `even_occ_T`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're calling a function within a function, so it is technically using recursion. I don't see an issue here, but you shouldn't rely on StackOverflow to get full marks for your exam.

`even_occ_T` appears to produce less bytecode, but runs slower than `even_occ_DO`

---

#### Code to analyze

```
import dis
from timeit import timeit

def even_occ_T(number):  # Tail Recursion
    def aux(number, sum_):
        if number == 0:
            return sum_
        else:
            return aux(number // 10, sum_ + (1 if number % 2 == 0 else 0))

    return aux(number, 0)

setup = '''
def even_occ_T(number):  # Tail Recursion
    def aux(number, sum_):
        if number == 0:
            return sum_
        else:
            return aux(number // 10, sum_ + (1 if number % 2 == 0 else 0))
    return aux(number, 0)
'''

print(timeit(stmt='''[even_occ_T(x) for x in range(0, 10)]''', setup=setup))
print('----------------------------------')
print(dis.dis(even_occ_T))


def even_occ_DO(number):  # Recursion using delayed operations
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (1 if number % 2 == 0 else 0) + even_occ_DO(number // 10)

setup = '''
def even_occ_DO(number):  # Recursion using delayed operations
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (1 if number % 2 == 0 else 0) + even_occ_DO(number // 10)
'''


print(timeit(stmt='''[even_occ_DO(x) for x in range(0, 10)]''', setup=setup))
print('----------------------------------')
print(dis.dis(even_occ_DO))
```

### Results

#### even_occ_T

```
5.360632722783559
----------------------------------
  5           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (aux)
              3 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object aux at 0x0000016683C66B70, file "C:/redacted.py", line 5>)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('even_occ_T.<locals>.aux')
             12 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             15 STORE_DEREF              0 (aux)

 11          18 LOAD_DEREF               0 (aux)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             24 LOAD_CONST               3 (0)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

#### even_occ_DO

```
3.4531076108028795
----------------------------------
 30           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 31          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             15 RETURN_VALUE

 33     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 BINARY_MODULO
             23 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             29 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       38
             32 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             35 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 41)
        >>   38 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
        >>   41 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (even_occ_DO)
             44 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
             47 LOAD_CONST               4 (10)
             50 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
             51 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             54 BINARY_ADD
             55 RETURN_VALUE
             56 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             59 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Various types of Recursion are(with some overlap):

- Linear Recursion
- Tail Recursion
- Binary Recursion
- Structural Recursion
- Accumulative Recursion
- Generative Recursion